# Network boot from a non-default NIC on a HP ProLiant G7 server

Tags: hp-proliant, pxe-boot

I need to force a ProLiant DL380 G7 server to PXE boot from a non-default (not Port 1) NIC.

So far I was unsuccessful in finding out how to do this, or if it's even possible.

I will be very grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: Why? Can't you just plug the PXE network into Port 1?

Comment: Which server model is this? The solution for a Gen8 blade is different than a ML350 or a DL380p...

Comment: @ChrisS: I can't, since the server is thousands of miles away.

Comment: @ewwhite: I amended my original question to specify the server model

Comment: @JoeChip Oh! G7. That's easier... See my updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On G7 and earlier servers, this can be changed in the BIOS. This assumes onboard interfaces.

(I hope you have ILO access)

Press `F9` during POST to get into the system BIOS menu (ROM-Based Setup Utility).

[image]

Follow the menus from `System Options > Embedded NICs > NIC X Boot Options`. 

Select the NIC you wish to boot from, and flip the `Network Boot` flag.

[image]

You'll need a power cycle to make that change effective.

---

Edit:

This is also available from the host OS (assuming the server is already running and has one).

```
[root@Tantalalicious ~]# hpasmcli 
HP management CLI for Linux (v2.0)
Copyright 2008 Hewlett-Packard Development Group, L.P.

hpasmcli> help enable pxe
USAGE: ENABLE PXE [ NIC1 | NIC2 | NIC3 | NIC4 ]: Enables PXE support on the embedded NICs.
```

Comment: It's the exact same on the Dell PE servers that I work with.

Comment: Although, on the HPs, can't you make a bunch of BIOS-level changes from the HP utilities, from the OS? Might not even need iLo.

Comment: @mfinni updated, but I'm assuming this is for initial OS installation... maybe?

Comment: And yes, it's an initial OS installation.

Comment: Ewwhite- sure, but it could also already have an OS that needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a way to set this from the RBSU (ROM-Based Setup Utility):

```
    SET CONFIG NIC 1 BOOT OPTIONS DISABLED
    SET CONFIG NIC 2 BOOT OPTIONS NETWORK BOOT
```

For other options, using

```
    SHOW CONFIG SCRIPT
```

is super-useful as a reference.